# Is there any security advantage of installing into AppData folder?

Tags: software, install

A lot of programs today allow to install into user appdata subdirectory to avoid installing system wide.

Is there any advantage of this?
Can programs installed system wide be more exploited than those installed locally?

Edit:
Updating question to be more clear:

I know the security risk of letting admin rights to execute program such as for example executing an installer or standalone program.

my concern is, once the application is installed into ProgramFiles vs AppData, is there any security difference?
The point here is that installed programs don't ask you for admin right anymore once installed, only when launching installer.
so my question is the part afterwards, after installation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427245/installing-in-program-files-vs-appdata you have an answer on SO, maybe you want a more security oriented answer ?